Is a reassembled once-tomei earthenware vessel tohor?
An earthenware vessel which becomes tomei cannot be purified in a mikvah {see Rashi Vayikro 11:33}.
The only way of purifying it is by breaking it {see Gr”a ibid}.
Rambam Mishneh Torah, Vessels 18:10 says that

If there is an earthenware fragment (of the broken tomei vessel)
that can serve as a receptacle, it is susceptible to impurity.

My question is whether a vessel glued back together from its broken bits which individually could not have served as a receptacle, would be impure or pure?
Related: Why does smashing an earthenware vessel resolve the problem of the absorbed material of a cooked offering which has gone beyond its time limit?

If it's pure, may the tree atop this page get up and walk across to the HNQ list! And may the sidebars of the site lean inwards! And may a site-wide banner descend from above proclaiming me correct!

@DoubleAA לא בשמים היא. :-) Pure - the question is whether they can become impure ever again.

Mishna Keilim 4:1 says:

‮הַחֶרֶס שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לַעֲמֹד מִפְּנֵי אָזְנוֹ, אוֹ שֶׁהָיָה בוֹ חִדּוּד וְהַחִדּוּד מַכְרִיעוֹ, טָהוֹר. נִטְּלָה הָאֹזֶן, נִשְׁבַּר הַחִדּוּד, טָהוֹר. רַבִּי יְהוּדָה מְטַמֵּא.
A potsherd that cannot stand unsupported on account of its handle, or a potsherd whose bottom is pointed and that point causes it to overbalance, is clean. If the handle was removed or the point was broken off it is still clean. R. Yehuda says that it is unclean.

The commentators explain that the dispute is whether, once broken and no longer capable of become tamei, potsherds can be made usable and again capable of becoming tamei. The halacha as recorded by Rambam (in Keilim 18:11, right after the one you quoted) is not like R. Yehuda, and once incapable of becoming tamei and losing its status as a vessel, a potsherd will never more be capable of becoming tamei:

‮הַחֶרֶס שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לֵישֵׁב כְּדֵי שֶׁיְּקַבֵּל מִפְּנֵי אָזְנוֹ אוֹ שֶׁהָיָה בּוֹ חִדּוּד וְהַחִדּוּד מַכְרִיעוֹ לְצַד אַחֵר הֲרֵי זֶה טָהוֹר אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁנִּטְּלָה הָאֹזֶן אוֹ נִשְׁבַּר הַחִדּוּד שֶׁכָּל כְּלִי חֶרֶס שֶׁטָּהַר שָׁעָה אַחַת אֵין לוֹ טֻמְאָה לְעוֹלָם:
When an earthenware container cannot rest on its base because of a handle or it has a protrusion and the protrusion causes it to lean to one side, it is pure even though the handle was removed or the protrusion was broken. The rationale is that whenever an earthenware container is considered as pure for even one moment, it is never susceptible to impurity again. [using language from Tosefta Keilim BK 3:4]

Rambam also repeats this in Keilim 19:14:

‮אֲבָל חֶרֶס שֶׁנִּקַּב אַחַר שֶׁפֵּרַשׁ מִן הַכְּלִי וְסָתַם הַנֶּקֶב בְּזֶפֶת אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא מַחֲזִיק רְבִיעִית טָהוֹר. שֶׁהַחֶרֶס שֶׁנִּקַּב בָּטַל שֵׁם כְּלִי מֵעָלָיו וְטָהַר וְכָל שֶׁטָּהַר בִּכְלִי חֶרֶס שָׁעָה אַחַת אֵין לוֹ טֻמְאָה לְעוֹלָם:
If, however, one plugged a hole in a shard with tar after it was separated from the k'li, it is pure, even though it is now capable of holding a revi'it. The rationale is that when a shard is perforated, it is no longer considered as a k'li and it is pure. And once an earthenware container has been considered as pure for even one moment, it never becomes susceptible to impurity again.

Indeed, an earthenware vessel can only become tamei after being fired in the oven (see Mishna Keilim 4:4), so simply reassembling potsherds does not make this new earthenware vessel capable of becoming tamei. It's irrelevant whether the pieces originally came from a tamei or tahor earthenware pot.
Note that this rule requires that the potsherds no longer be considered vessels (like in your question). If a pot developed holes such that it no longer served its function, it can no longer become tamei, but remains a vessel; if repaired, it can become tamei again (see Mishna Keilim 3:4, for example).
